# QML ListView overwriten with buttons - but should be in different rows

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

In below code I have 2 rows .
In first I have buttons and in second a ListView. Why are they overwriten in the display, what's wrong ?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Page {
 id: test


  Column {
      spacing: units.gu(1)
      id: pageLayout
      anchors {
          margins: units.gu(2)
          fill: parent
      }

      Row {
          spacing: units.gu(1)
          Button {
              objectName: "button1"
              color: "white"
              text: i18n.tr("Help")
          }
          Button {
              objectName: "button2"
              color: "black"
              text: i18n.tr("Search")
          }
      }

      Row {
          id: listarea
          spacing: units.gu(1)
          anchors.fill: parent

          ListModel {
              id: fruitModel
              ListElement {
                  name: "Apple"
                  cost: 2.45
              }
              ListElement {
                  name: "Orange"
                  cost: 3.25
              }
              ListElement {
                  name: "Banana"
                  cost: 1.95
              }
          }

         ListView {
             anchors.fill: parent
             model: fruitModel
             delegate: Row {
                 Text { text: "Fruit: " + name }
                 Text { text: "Cost: $" + cost }
             }
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to specify that the second row goes below the first one using:

```
anchors.top: buttonRow.bottom
```

I also modified the way you render your ListView by calculating `listarea` height from the number of elements in the list.

The final QML code is below, included in a `Mainview` so that it's ready to be tested with `qmlscene`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    width: units.gu(60)
    height: units.gu(60)

    Page {
        id: test

        Column {
            spacing: units.gu(1)
            id: pageLayout
            anchors {
                margins: units.gu(2)
                fill: parent
            }

            Row {
                id: buttonRow
                spacing: units.gu(1)
                Button {
                    objectName: "button1"
                    color: "white"
                    text: i18n.tr("Help")
                }
                Button {
                    objectName: "button2"
                    color: "black"
                    text: i18n.tr("Search")
                }
            }

            Row {
                id: listarea
                spacing: units.gu(1)
                anchors.top: buttonRow.bottom
                height: myList.count * units.gu(2)

                ListModel {
                    id: fruitModel
                    ListElement {
                        name: "Apple"
                        cost: 2.45
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "Orange"
                        cost: 3.25
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "Banana"
                        cost: 1.95
                    }
                }

                ListView {
                    id: myList
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    model: fruitModel
                    delegate: Row {
                        Text { text: "Fruit: " + name }
                        Text { text: "Cost: $" + cost }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Super, that fixed it, there is only one problem with it: If the ListView have many records/rows, they are not scrolable.

Comment: Please start a new question if you'd like the ListView component to be scrollable.

Comment: And please upvote (^) my answer too now that you have enough reputation to do it.